# I'm using G1ANT software and in advance lesson no. 3 I'm getting error while handling the enter key btnK so what should I do to remove it properly

Tags: g1ant

I'm using G1ANT software and in advance lesson no. 3 I'm getting error while handling the enter key btnK. So what should I do to remove it properly?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agjhd.jpg I've tried everything to overcome that even by trying class call but that's also not working

Answer (score 1):

You can get the xpath of that search key and then paste that in your g1ant studio and give search by xpath at the end.